Creación de archivo .i
Estoy tratando de usar un wrapper para pasar una librería de C++ a una de Python. Ya tengo la clase definida con sus métodos, pero me falta hacer el archivo .i para empezar a crear el makefile que construirá la librería y el wrapper. La librería es sobre grafos dirigidos en donde alguien puede introducir un nuevo nodo, meter un arco y encontrar arcos y caminos. Para lograr eso, utilizo vectores.
Este es el archivo .i hasta ahora. ¿Qué me falta?
%module grafo
%{
#include"grafo.h"
}%

%include "std_string.i"
%include"std_vector.i"

namespace std{
    %template(vecint) vec<int>;
};

class grafo{
    void matriz();
    void orden();
    int n;
    int arc;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> ady;
    grafo(int);
    void add_arco(int, int);
    int add_nodo();
    bool hay_arco(int, int);
    bool hay_camino(int, int);
};

`%module grafo
%{
#include"grafo.h"
}%

